Can Azure Document Intelligence Custom Models Extract Multiple Values for a Single Key?
I'm currently using Azure Document Intelligence Custom Models to extract entities from documents. As per the documentation, this service is designed to extract key-value pairs. However, in my specific use case, a single key might have multiple associated values.
My questions are:

Does Azure Document Intelligence Custom Models support extracting multiple values for a single key?
If this is not supported, are there any alternative services or approaches within Azure or other platforms that can handle multiple values per key during document processing?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried training a custom model, but I'm only able to extract one value per key, even when there are multiple values present in the document.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
